# Construction of tensor product of module.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let
$R$ commutative ring
$M,N$ module

$F(M\times N)$ free $R$ module

$I$ the ideal generated by elements of the form

$$a(m,n)-(m,an), (a \in R, m \in M, n \in N). $$

Is that true any element of $I$ has at least one coefficient not equal to $1$.

What I want to do is below.
Let

$L$ abelian module

$f:M\times N \rightarrow L$ an $R$ balanced map.

I want to show $f$ factors through $F(M\times N)/I$.

To show that, I have to show

I can uniquely choose the representative  of $F(M\times N)/I$ so that all of its coefficients are $1$ unless it itself is $0$.

Of course I understand how to construct tensor products and the proof that the construction is appropriate.
Therefore, what I would like you to tell me here is whether my proof policy is appropriate or not.

Comment: Something is not right. If $(a-1) \cdot (m,n) = a(m,n) - (m,n) \in I$ for all $a,m,n$ then letting $a = 2$ gives $(m,n) \in I$, so $I = F(M \times N)$ and $F(M \times N)/I = 0$. Or do you not assume that $R$ contains $1$?

Comment: I had a huge mistake and corrected it.